# Allow `.php` extension in `css` files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am doing minification and combining of files on the fly with the help of some tutorials.

[Click Here](https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php) to see what i am using and this is saved in `style.css.php` file.

> In .htaccess file i have denied PHP extension to be used on website as per below code

```
# remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L] 

# restrict .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^\ ]+\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule \.php$ / [F,L]
```

and it is working all fine.
But when i am tring to use

> <link href="css/styles.css.php" />

then i am getting error that `.php` is not permitted. 
**So, how can i make sure that .php extension is allowed on links and scripts.**

Comment: `.php extension is allowed on links and scripts` - Web server doesn't how a request is coming to it. It can only act only based on the URI, query string, user agent etc

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

this hiddes .php ext, try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

or try

```
css/styles.css.php
```

without .php ext.

Comment: without php i can use but i want to use with php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing what you're working on based on the link you provided, so forgive me if this isn't what you're looking for or I've misunderstood. 
But you should be able to remove the ".css" and simply leave the ".php" and have it as

```
<link ...  href='css/style.php'/>
```